# Best practice for using github and AWS lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm writing AWS lambda's in the browser and want to improve my version control process from the present setup, which is to copy paste the lambda code into a text file and manually commit to a repository.

Is there a better (and preferably straight-forward) way of using AWS lambda with version control (in my case git/github)?

Comment: Why don't you use an IaC template?
Serverless Framework or AWS Sam? SF is super easy to get started and helps you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

There is an example in [this git repository](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-lambda-deploy) provided by AWS.

It is a bit too big to retype it here.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to get your code sync with GitHub

https://npm.io/package/aws-lambda-sync